# Cannot read property 'map' undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working with some information that I pulled from an API.  The array that I have looks something like this

```
var hours = 
[
 [
  "2015-10-21T13:00:00Z",
  "2015-10-21T21:00:00Z"
],
 [
  "2015-10-22T13:00:00Z",
  "2015-10-22T21:00:00Z"
 ]
]
```

I tried looping through the array and calling out something if a specific time is called.

```
var res = hours.map(function(v) {
  if (v == '2015-10-22T13:00:00Z'){
      console.log("this is my test")
  }
});
```

However when I try i get this error at the property of 'map' is undefined.

Now the strange thing is I tried substituting a super small array instead of the one i pulled from the api.

```
array = [ [ '1', '2' ], [ '1', '3' ], [ '3', '4' ] ]
```

and when I tried using 'array' instead of 'hours'

```
var res = array.map(function(v) {
```

I didn't get the error.  Are you not able to manipulate and play with arrays that come from an API? why does my simple small little 'array' work, but not 'hours'?

I ultimately need to flag specific dates in my 'hours' array.

Comment: Where is `hours` coming from?  Are you *sure* it's an array (and not an object)?  What does `console.log(hours);` show?

Comment: Did this array come from a ajax call or something and returned as a JSON string that needs to be parsed perhaps?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I don't think it needs to be parsed.  I say that because what I have listed is exactly how it looks in the preview within the console.

Comment: Is the response JSON?

Comment: @kdweber89: What do you get if you `console.log(hours);`?  What about `console.log(hours.length);`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat if i try that, I get the digit 7. (For the sake of the question, i  condensed it, however it lists an entire week of information, and it is listed as a large array)

Comment: @kdweber89 Might be worth a try to parse it. JSON.parse(responseArray)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check for the response type of the AJAX request. In case, its a JSON string(most commonly), you should parse the response before you actually iterate over the array.

```
var hours = JSON.parse(YOUR_RESPONSE);
```

Also, since its a multi-dimenstional array, you need to check for `v[0]` and not `v`

Do it like this:

```js
var hours = [
  [
    "2015-10-21T13:00:00Z",
    "2015-10-21T21:00:00Z"
  ],
  [
    "2015-10-22T13:00:00Z",
    "2015-10-22T21:00:00Z"
  ]
];

var res = hours.map(function(v) {
  if (v[0] == '2015-10-22T13:00:00Z') { //v[0] not just v
    console.log("this is my test")
  }
});
```